# why can't taylor series capture memory effects?

Tags: taylor-series

I am trying to understand when to use Volterra series.I found this on wikipedia 'The Volterra series is a model for non-linear behavior similar to the Taylor series. It differs from the Taylor series in its ability to capture 'memory' effects.'
My question is: why can't Taylor series capture memory effects?
More generally, when do you decide to approximate a function with Taylor series, when with a Volterra series, and when with neither? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Volterra_and_Wiener_serieshttp://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Volterra_and_Wiener_series